# Factorial recursion Exception not given in java 1.6

Tags: java, exception, recursion, factorial, throws

Why I am not getting any Exception in the following code? 
After running this code I am getting an infinite loop mentioning at test.fact(t.java:32)
 No Compile-Time Error was found.

```
class test
{

    int fact(int m) throws Exception
    {
        if (m==1)
        {
        return 1;
        }
    else
        return (fact ((m-1)*m));
    }
}

class main
{
    public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception
    {
        test t = new test();
        System.out.println(t.fact(5));
    }
}
```

while say for example i am using

```
return(a+b);
```

it executes successfully whats the problem with the recursion
to show an error???

Comment: You're not seeing a StackOverflowError?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry this is off topic but I love your name

Comment: @JakobBowyer and i liked your comment.

Comment: Also, note that StackOverflowError is a runtime exception. It's impossible to detect at compile time.

Comment: @Kiyura related to the halting problem?

Comment: @Kiyura: exactly. But when he runs the code above, he should see this error, given that his fact int parameters actually increase on recursion.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, yup, I was just addressing his apparent concern that he couldn't see this problem before running it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Why the StackOverflowError not caught by either the compiler of the exception, so how to handle that error in future. so why the infinite loop occurs.

Comment: Because, compiler will not know what integer you are about to pass . You can get the input from the user at runtime and pass it to the fact method. Thats the reason this kind of error/exceptions are not handled at compile time.On a side not, any error or exception that extends RunTimeException will not be handled by compiler. Have a look at : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: sorry since the loop exceeded with infinite error log I cannot able to see the stack overflow error but now i saw it.

Answer (score 3):

You have a mistake in the return value expression of fact method.
It should be

```
      return fact(m-1) * m;
```

Comment: while say for example i amd using return(a+b), it executes successfully whats the problem with the recursion to show an error???

Answer (score 0):

```
      return (fact ((m-1)*m));
```

returns

```
fact(20)
```

which returns

```
fact (380)
```

which returns

```
fact (379*380)
```

which   ....

which never returns anything and should make a stack overflow (too much memory is used on the call stack).

```
           return fact(m-1) * m;
```

should work.

I highly recommend you reading again the basics, and examples ( here, for example - http://www.toves.org/books/java/ch18-recurex/index.html)

Try  writing the recursion tree yoursels, in order to understand what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to calculate factorial using cycle (with no recursion):

```
int fact(int m) throws Exception
{
    int f = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; f *= ++i);
    return f;
}
```